# retrieve selected items from jquery MultiSelect

Tags: jquery, multi-select

Simple question but I just can't find the answer. I'm using the 'a beautiful site' jquery multiSelect dropdown select plugin <[link](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-multiSelect/demo/)>. Everything seems to work using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contact).multiSelect(); 
});
```

Then in the body:

```
<select id="contact" name="contact_list[]" multiple="multiple" size="5"> 
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Alekseev">Alekseev</option>
  <option value="Bettis">Bettis</option>
  <option value="Chlachula">Chlachula</option>
  <option value="Kohfeld">Kohfeld</option>
  <option value="Maher">Maher</option>
  <option value="Muhs">Muhs</option>
</select>
```

The simple question is: how do I retrieve a JavaScript array of the selected values equivalent to the simple non-jquery:

```
var contactName = document.getElementById('contact').value;
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var arr = $("#contact").val();
console.log(arr);  // ["Bettis", "Chlachula"]
```

Comment: Many thanks. Unfortunately this doesn't do the job. I'm sure it's obvious but I just couldn't find it. I've now switched to Eric Hynds multiselect dropdown plugin and it's working really well [<link here>](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget).